# If the return type 'Object' works with all the value types to return, why do we bother declaring specific return values for functions?

Tags: java, function

I'm currently an intern trying to learn from more experienced developers and one of them declares all functions to return Objects. I asked him why and he replied "It works with everything".

Well then, why should I declare functions with specific return value types?

Comment: Here's a box, you have to interact with that box, but you're not allowed to open said box, you just have to guess and if you guess it wrong, it will explode

Comment: *"more experienced"* ... *"declares all functions to return Objects"* - pick one. That person is not experienced nor is that person a good programmer. I suggest you never ask that person again. Try to find one who actually knows how to program good stuff.

Comment: Please don't edit noise into your question. You want to thank somebody for their good answer, then upvote it (if you have >15 reputation points) and/or accept the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea is how you want to interface the returned object, all classes in java extends Object so yes you can do this, but when specifying the return type to be Object, Object will be the actual interface, so you will need a cast to be able to use any additional methods or attributes defined in your specific class.

In addition to the headache of casting you cannot safely assume that the return object is really an instance of your presumed class, so you will need to check also if the return object is an instance of the class you want to be interfaced by.

Comment: Thank you sir. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

This example might help you:

> You buy a new **phone** from amazon, but amazon sends you a **pencil** because
>   amazon must not send a phone, it can send anything to you.

The same accounts for the method you mentioned, the method just returns an `Object` so if I expect a `String` nothing prevents the method to not send a `String` but an `Integer`.